# Android ormlite update listview

Tags: java, android, listview, ormlite

I use `ormlite` in my application and have problem with updating `listview`.

Here my code which update `listview`.

```
    try {
        Dao deadlineDao = DatabaseManager.getInstance().getHelper().getDeadlineDao();
        deadlines = (List<Deadline>)deadlineDao.queryForAll();
        adapter = new DeadlineAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.deadline_item_row, deadlines);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        deadlineListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        deadlineListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It update when I close and open this `Activity`. I don't find answer to this question anywhere.

Thanks for help!

.

Answer (score 0):

if you are calling above function within a asynctask, try this,

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    deadlineListView.notifyDataSetChanged();
})};
```